# Add class names (stored in array) to columns

Tags: javascript

I need to add different class names to table columns. If there are more columns than class names they should be assigned equally. So let's say I have some variables like:

```
var tableColumns = 5,
    skipColumns = 1,
    classNames = ['s','m','l'];
```

In the end the class names for the columns should be more or less like (for this example)

```
column 2 -> "s" // Column 1 is skipped
column 3 -> "m"
column 4 + 5 -> "l"
```

or (if that's easier to do) like this

```
column 2 + 3 -> "s" // Column 1 is skipped
column 4 -> "m"
column 5 -> "l"
```

I tried to do this with two for loops, but it doesn't really work for every column count

```
var tableColumns = 5,
    skipColumns = 1,
    classNames = ['s','m','l'],

    columnsPerClass = Math.round(( tableColumns - skipColumns ) / classNames.length );

if( tableColumns > classNames.length ) {
  for ( var i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++ ) {
    // Loop through all class names
    for ( var j = 0; j < columnsPerClass; j++ ) {
      console.log( 
          'Column ' + ( i * columnsPerClass + j + skipColumns + 1 ) + 
          ' / Class name: ' + classNames[ i ]
      );
      // Add class names to columns
    }
  }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/qixufemu/4/edit?js,console

For example if I set `tableColumns` to 5 and `skipColumns` to 1 the output is:

```
"Column 2 / Class name: s"
"Column 3 / Class name: m"
"Column 4 / Class name: l"
```

So column 5 is missing in the output.

**EDIT:**
I think it wasn't quite clear, what `skipColumns` does. So I quickly created three examples. 
[image]

Comment: With 3 classes and 7 columns (skippig the first) what would you want the output to be? `s,m,l,s,m,l` or `s,s,m,m,l,l`?

Comment: @RobH With 7 columns and the first one skipped the output should be `s,s,m,m,l,l`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think i quite understand what the skipColumns variable is supposed to mean, but i tried the following script to achieve what you described:

```
var columns = 7;
var classNames = ['s', 'm', 'l'];
var skipColumns = [3];
var colsPerClass = Math.round((columns - skipColumns.length) / classNames.length);
var colClassNames = [];
for (var i = 0; i < classNames.length; i++) {
    var currentClassCount = 1;
    while (currentClassCount <= colsPerClass) {
        colClassNames[colClassNames.length] = classNames[i];
        currentClassCount++;
    }
}
if (colClassNames.length < columns) {
    var currentClassCount = 1;
    colsPerClass = 1;
    i = 0;
    while (currentClassCount <= colsPerClass) {
        colClassNames[colClassNames.length] = classNames[i];
        currentClassCount++;
        i = i < (classNames.length) ? i++ : 0;
    }
}
console.log(colClassNames);
function findValue(val, array) {
    var iterator = array.length;
    if (iterator <= 0)
        return false;
    while (iterator--) {
        if (array[iterator] == val){
            return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
var skippedColumns = 0;
var columnsWithClassNames = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
    if (!findValue(i, skipColumns)) {
        columnsWithClassNames[columnsWithClassNames.length] = { ColNumber: i };
        columnsWithClassNames[columnsWithClassNames.length - 1].ClassName =         colClassNames[i - (1 + skippedColumns)];
    } else {
        skippedColumns++;
    }
}
console.log(columnsWithClassNames);
```

and i was able to achieve the result you described in your response to @RobH. It is possible to make this operation a bit more efficient, but i guess we need to know the impact of the skipColumns variable.

In the current form, the script will result in an array of JSON objects, containing the column number and the class name for that column as follows (based on your example):

```
[Object { ColNumber=1, ClassName="s"}, Object { ColNumber=2, ClassName="s"}, Object {     ColNumber=3, ClassName="m"}, Object { ColNumber=4, ClassName="m"}, Object { ColNumber=5,     ClassName="l"}, Object { ColNumber=6, ClassName="l"}]
```

This might not be your desired format, but the algorithm seems to achieve what you intend.

Comment: Thanks alot, I edited my question and added some examples for `skipColumns`. I hope `skipColumns` is easier to understand now? Your code works for `columnCount` of 7 and `skipColumns` of 1. But if I change `columnCount` to 5 the fourth column is undefined. It should output something like `s,s,m,l` or `s,m,l,l` though (whatever is easier to do, both is fine).

Comment: After experimenting a bit I think it's doable with `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round` and the `%` Modulo operator like `(columns - skipColumns) % classNames.length`. I'm still not sure how to put that all in one function though.

Comment: You're right, i found several issues with the previous implementation, and i have updated the algorithm in my answer to reflect your comments. It will now work for values of the 'columnCount' of 5 and others, though when using the value 5 and a skipColumn of 1, the resulting distribution is 's,m,l,s' instead of 's,s,m,l' or 's,m,l,l' because i had a hard time thinking of an efficient way to implement that distribution due to lack of details. But you should not have issues improving my suggestion to achieve it.

Comment: Thanks for your help... I simplified the code a bit and fixed the issue with `s,m,l,s`. As far as I have tested it there are no further issues: http://jsbin.com/foxisamihave/1/edit?js,console